# Single cluster endpoint url for a MongoDB replica set?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I currently have a couple of replica sets and for each one, the url is something like this:

```
mongodb://host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017,host4:27017,host5:27017/database?replicaSet=repname
```

Problems with this approach:

- I don't always have all 5 instances up.
- If I want to add more replicas or change the port, I need to change the url
- If I change the url, I need to let my clients know (other applications)

The ideal solution would be something similar to [aws aurora cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Connect.html), like this url:

```
mongodb://mongocluster:27017?replicaSet=repname
```

My questions are:

- What is the best approach to do that?
- Is it worth doing?
- Is my current solution wrong?

Comment: That's not how it actually works. Your app only provides a "seed". The actual configuration is read from the replica set itself. See the official specification [Server Discovery And Monitoring (SDAM)](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#clients-use-the-hostnames-listed-in-the-replica-set-config-not-the-seed-list). So your application need actually only contact **one** member in order to discover the current nodes that are "up".

Comment: Yes, but isn't that too optimistic? what if that single node is down? you would tell me to use half of my servers as my url, but half now could be a quarter tomorrow and I would have the same problem.

Comment: In all honesty, if you cannot keep 1 in 5 servers up then you have bigger problems. I'm really just pointing you at the details you don't appear to be aware of. The general read is that your question skirts dangerously close to actually being about replica set configuration rather than a connection string and therfore is off-topic for Stack Overflow where that is the case. It's essentially the difference between asking "do a need to add each replica set member to my app connection?" which is *No you do not, as is explained*.

Comment: If for some reason you think you need a completely "amorphous list" of hosts that is constantly changing throughout the whole configuration. Then you have some concepts incorrect and you should state your situation on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Very good reading thanks, what I got wrong is `your application need actually only contact one member in order to discover the current nodes that are "up".` where you meant that contacting *any* member is enough.

Comment: Another key point: `if the response is from a primary, the client MUST remove all hostnames not listed. In this case, the client disconnects from "host_alias" and tries "host1" and "host2"` that tells me that is safe to use an alias to any member that is up as a seed, which is what I wanted. Or did I got it wrong?